# how to maintain scroll for only table which is inside div tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, web, scrollbar

I have to maintain scroll for only my table which is inside div tag.
    in table have 500 entries so its bad habit to give scroll to page.
    so i m maintainig vertical scroll to only div and no scroll for page.
    and for any resolution i use javascript code.
    i have to maintain table bottom aligned.
    Means in whole page i will scroll only div contents.
    i used below code it give me scroll to div tag but scroll to page also getting.
    i m using master page.

```
    <div id="divScroll" style="width: 100%;">
        <table id="tableWorkList" class="csstablelist" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
    ....</tr>//**500 rows in table**
    </table>
    </div>


function resolutionIndependent()
        {
            var myHeight;
            if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth)
            {
                myHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
            }
            if (document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth)
            {
                myHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
            }
            if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight)
            {
                myHeight = window.innerHeight;
            }
            var divScroll = document.getElementById('divScroll');
            divScroll.style.height = parseFloat(myHeight) + 'px';
            divScroll.style.overflow = "auto";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
overflow: auto;
```

in the style tag of div, and do set some `height` and `width` of a div.

Comment: using above code table is not bottom aligned and also its look good in 1024*768 but i make resolution higher then it makes some space in bottom so i have to make resolution independent

Answer (score 2):

```
#divScroll{ overflow:auto; height : 200px; width : 600px; }
```

will work for you.

Comment: using above code table is not bottom aligned and also its look good in 1024*768 but i make resolution higher then it makes some space in bottom so i have to make resolution independent

Comment: <div id="divScroll" style="width: 100%; height: 90%; overflow: auto;">

Comment: if i give hieght in % then scroll disappears

Answer (score 0):

Make it .... for example

```
  <div id="divScroll" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;overflow : auto;">
```

Comment: using above code is not bottom aligned and also its look good in 1024*768 but i make resolution higher then it makes some space in bottom i have to make resolution independent